Problem in natural language api integration withf firestore
I am developing an app in kotlin , it has a part , where i have the reviews like feature where i will post review of something ,and it get stored in firestore , i have also used firebase for authentication , now i tried a lot , that exclude method n many solution i found online , but still i am getting that error :
below are some lines of it
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.5.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.5.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.5.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.5.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.5.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.5.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)`

many lines like this , here i am attaching my build.gradle(module level) :
import org.gradle.internal.impldep.org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories.CategoryFilter.exclude

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.google.gms.google.services)
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin")

}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.xplore"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.xplore"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation (libs.androidx.appcompat.v141)
    implementation (libs.material.v150)
    implementation (libs.androidx.constraintlayout.v213)
    implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)
    implementation (libs.firebase.auth.v2101)
    implementation (libs.firebase.firestore.ktx.v2401)
    implementation (libs.android.maps.utils.v223) // Make sure to use the latest version

    implementation (libs.play.services.maps.v1802)
    implementation (libs.play.services.location.v1901)
    implementation (libs.play.services.places.v1700)

    // Glide for image loading
    implementation (libs.glide.v4130)
    annotationProcessor (libs.compiler.v4130)

    // Retrofit for networking
    implementation (libs.retrofit)
    implementation (libs.converter.gson)

    // Google Cloud Natural Language API

    implementation (libs.google.auth.library.oauth2.http.v180)
    implementation (libs.cloud.google.cloud.language.v212)


    testImplementation (libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation (libs.androidx.junit.v113)
    androidTestImplementation (libs.androidx.espresso.core.v340)
}

very frustrated now , any help folks
i have tried that exclude method with exclude the proto module and everything  but still the error came again.
